# Select multiple non-consecutive lines of text

Tags: eclipse, text-editing

In Eclipse 4.2 Workbench, I'd like to select multiple lines of non-consecutive text at the same time.

For example, I want to highlight and copy line 1, 4, and 10 without having to highlight, copy and paste each one individually.

Comment: Eclipse what? it is the foundation of a bunch of stuff.

Comment: Eclipse 4.2 Workbench